# Changing listener IP on default TCP endpoint via DDL statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL server instances that are listening on all available interfaces (0.0.0.0). I need them to listen on one specific IP only. I also need to automate this configuration change, e.g. via a DDL statement.

My strategy is to use `ALTER ENDPOINT` to change `LISTENER_IP` on the default TDS endpoint.

I ran `SELECT * FROM sys.endpoints` and discovered the `TSQL Default TCP` endpoint.

Then I executed the following SQL command:

```
ALTER ENDPOINT "TSQL Default TCP"
AS TCP (
    LISTENER_IP = 192.168.4.22
)
```

This produced the following error.

```
Msg 7871, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The clause 'AS TCP' is not valid for this endpoint type.
```

This doesn't make sense to me. It is definitely a TCP endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The clause 'AS TCP' is not valid for this endpoint type.

This is because you are trying to alter a **deafult** endpoint, and the only options you can change for this are `STATE` and `AUTHORIZATION`:
[Network Protocols and TDS Endpoints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191220(v=sql.105).aspx)

[image]

So you can only stop this endpoint and create other endpoints.